# Jquery - Exibir dados de comentários

Tags: jquery, asp

Estou tentando retornar em JQuery dados de comentários e ao fim um `form` para inserir mais comentários.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#exibir-comentario").click(function(){

          var valor = $("#exibir-comentario").attr('rel');
          var dados = $("#resposta-form"+valor+"")
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "comentarios.asp?id_questao="+valor+"",
              success: function(resposta) {
                  dados.html(resposta);
              },
              beforeSend: function(){
                dados.html('Buscando...');
              },
              error: function(data) {
                  dados.html('Erro ao buscar!');
              }
        });
      return false;
      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%questao=1%>
  <a id="exibir-comentario" rel="<%=questao%>" href="#">Exibir fomulário</a>
  <div id="resposta-form<%=questao%>"></div>
<%questao=2%>
  <a id="exibir-comentario" rel="<%=questao%>" href="#">Exibir fomulário</a>
  <div id="resposta-form<%=questao%>"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Porém o segundo link não retorna.

Solucionei colocando o id dinâmico e fazendo a classe receber o click.

```
//carrega comentarios
$(function() {
    $("a.link").click(function(){
          var valor = $(this).attr('id');
          var dados = $("#resposta-form"+valor+"")
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "comentarios.asp?id_questao="+valor+"",
              success: function(resposta) {
                  dados.html(resposta);
              },
              beforeSend: function(){
                dados.html('Buscando...');
              },
              error: function(data) {
                  dados.html('Erro ao buscar!');
              }
        });
      return false;
      });
});
```

Agora ocorreu o seguinte.  Consegui trazer o fomulário e os comentários. Tô tentando enviar os dados do form fazendo exatamente como fiz com o script anterior, porém como o form já vem carregado, não vai.

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema parece estar nos `IDs`, você está usando o mesmo id para os dois  objetos e apenas um deles está sendo reconhecido pelo script.

Usa mais ou menos assim:

```
<%questao=1%>
  <a id="exibir-comentario-a" rel="<%=questao%>" href="#">Exibir fomulário</a>
  <div id="resposta-form<%=questao%>"></div>
<%questao=2%>
  <a id="exibir-comentario-b" rel="<%=questao%>" href="#">Exibir fomulário</a>
  <div id="resposta-form<%=questao%>"></div>
```

Você também vai precisar alterar o seu jquery para entender e tratar os dois IDs.

Comment: colocar uma variavel pra receber esse id antes de executar a função.

Comment: pensando bem...só entra na função ao clicar, não posso fazer isso.

Comment: Solucionei, coloquei o id dinamico e dei o click na classe.